# I have issue in BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

***NOTE: I have surfing stackoverflow answer before asking this, so don't make it duplicate***

I am trying to create app which is run in background mode,there is not any activity in my application,
my application should work like
 After 10 minutes it will check call log and if it was changed from last then it should send call log to server.
I have tried with boot_completed intent

```
 public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("schedulereceiver", "starting schedule");
    }
}
```

and i have declare receiver like

```
 <receiver
            android:name="com.ixo.BootUpReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

I have added permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I want to clear, I am testing on 4.2 version, and its nexus tablet, hope it is not creating problems

if I am checking log

```
> 02-26 12:31:10.809: W/ActivityManager(478): No content provider found
> for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/Tracker.apk 

02-26 12:31:10.809: I/PackageManager(478): Copying native libraries to
> /data/app-lib/vmdl1018712645 

02-26 12:31:10.889: D/dalvikvm(478): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1347K, 13% free 13294K/15184K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 62ms 02-26 12:31:10.889: I/PackageManager(478): Removing non-system package:com.ixo.tracker 

02-26 12:31:10.899: I/ActivityManager(478): Force stopping package com.ixo.tracker appid=10100 user=-1 

02-26 12:31:10.989: I/PackageManager(478): Running dexopt on: com.ixo.tracker 

02-26 12:31:10.989: I/PackageManager(478): Package com.ixo.tracker codePath changed from
/data/app/com.ixo.tracker-2.apk to /data/app/com.ixo.tracker-1.apk; Retaining data and using new 

02-26 12:31:11.049: D/dalvikvm(2434): DexOpt: 'Landroid/annotation/SuppressLint;' has an earlier definition; blocking out
```

***Update***

some time I am getting log like

```
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171): Exception when retrieving package:com.ixo.tracker
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171): android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.ixo.tracker
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:80)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.retrieveAppEntry(InstalledAppDetails.java:621)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.refreshUi(InstalledAppDetails.java:640)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.onActivityResult(InstalledAppDetails.java:534)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5297)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3315)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3362)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-26 13:42:22.139: E/InstalledAppDetails(6171):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 13:42:22.169: W/AppSecurityPermissions(6171): Couldn't retrieve permissions for package:com.ixo.tracker
```

**UPDATE**

if it is not working in 3.1 and above, is there any alternative to develop above.

Answer (score 2):

As a security fix, new versions of Android will not allow a BroadcastReceiver to receive BOOT_COMPLETE until it has been launched by the user-  which requires there to be an activity that they launch.  It's annoying, but you'll have to add an activity of some sort.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, so you mean it is not possible without any activity?

Comment: Are you sure about this? Can you provide a link that confirms this? Also, what do you mean by "new versions of Android"?

Comment: It didn't use to do that, sometime back in 2.x.  I'm unsure where it changed.  I'll look for a link briefly, but its late.  I've run into this problem before and that's where I found it, but that was 6-12 months ago.

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html   And from there is linked http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18225  Google confirms this is working as intended, it appears it was changed in 3.1

Comment: @GabeSechan ok so is there any other option/solution for my issue

Comment: The only one I know of is to have some sort of Activity.  Not saying there are no others, but anything would require a user to take some action.

Comment: @Paul you have any idea? or suggestion

Comment: It's now by design and there is no way around it. Apps are in a force-stop state until user starts the app manually, eg those apps do not receive any events whatsoever. User force-stopping an app will also put that app in that particular state again. So Gabe's answer is the right answer and you might want to consider accepting it, even if we all don't like it.

Comment: And this is a Good Thing (TM). It means that the user is in charge of his/hers phone, and not any random app the user installed.